# How to access SQL Web of t2.large windows EC2 instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have purchased a t2.large EC2 instance with Windows and SQL Web. Now am not able to find out the access the SQL part of it. Do I need to create a new RDS instance to avail the SQL Web? Will I be able to host the SQL Server on the same t2.large instance? Please advice. Am not pretty familiar with Windows.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you mean by "not able to find out the access the SQL part of it"?

Comment: I checked it under the RDS instances but couldn't find any instance. How do I create databases / Access it from my code? As I said, Am pretty new to Windows and SQL Server.

Comment: You don't need RDS. SQL Server is installed on the machine. Are you able to connect to the EC2 instance by remote desktop?

Comment: Yes, Am able to connect to EC2 Instance. The problem is, am not able to locate the SQL service.

Comment: Hi All, It was the problem with the AMI I chose while creating the instance. I fixed it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem with the AMI I chose while creating the instance. I fixed it. Thank you all for your help.